# Циклический сдвиг элементов массива влево/вправо на k позиций

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl

Дан массив размера N и число k `(0<k<5,k<N)`.

Осуществить циклический сдвиг элементов массива влево/вправо на k позиций.

Comment: Давайте я дам подсказку, вы напишете код - а то так и тянет закрыть вопрос как учебное задание... Я на примере, а вы подумайте. Сделать реверс массива очень просто, - циклом с двух концов менять элементы местами. Пусть есть `abcdefghij`. Делаем реверс - `jihgfedcba`. Выбираем, скажем, 4 первых элемента и делаем реверс их и отдельно - остальных. `ghijabcdef`. Похоже на циклический сдвиг вправо на 4 элемента? А теперь - вперед, пишите!

Answer (score 6):

Ладно, тот случай, когда вопрос хоть и учебный, но поучительный в смысле алгоритма. Поэтому отвечу.

Общий алгоритм циклического сдвига легко реализуется с помощью обращения порядка элементов. Рассмотрим, например, массив

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l
```

который надо сдвинуть на 4 позиции вправо. Это значит, что слева должны оказаться элементы `i j k l`. При обращении порядка элементов они именно там и окажутся, правда, в обратном порядке:

```
l k j i h g f e d c b a
```

Но если теперь развернуть только первые 4 элемента, они оказываются на своем месте...

```
i j k l h g f e d c b a
```

Осталось развернуть вторую часть - остальные 8 элементов:

```
i j k l a b c d e f g h
```

Вот и все, мы получили, что нужно.

Реализовать это легко с использование алгоритма `reverse` стандартной библиотеки, с использованием итераторов - начала последовательности, средины (куда сдвигать первый элемент) и конца:

```
template<typename BidirIt>
void rot(BidirIt first, BidirIt mid, BidirIt last)
{
    reverse(first,last);
    reverse(first,mid);
    reverse(mid,last);
}
```

Ну, а вот и [применение](https://ideone.com/IiFqbg):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s = "abcdefghij";
    rot(s.begin(),s.begin()+3,s.end());
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

А теперь самое интересное: все это написано **для понимания**, и не более того, потому что в стандартной библиотеке есть симпатичный алгоритм [`rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), который выполняет *левый* циклический сдвиг элементов диапазона, так что в нормальной, так сказать, production-программе лучше использовать его...