# почему сдвиг элементов массива влево не работает?

Tags: c, массивы, rotate

код должен сдвигать элементы в массиве влево либо вправо в зависимости от параметра k
сдвиг вправо работает
влево же, при консольном вводе ничего не двигается

```
#include <stdio.h>

//функции
void rshiftonce(int arr[], int length);
void rshift(int arr[], int length, int times);
void rlo(int array[], int len);
void rl(int array[], int len, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int n; //n=размер массива, k=сколько раз будем двигать
    scanf("%i", &n);

    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) { //цикл, идущий по индексам массива и заполняющий их числами
        scanf("%i ", &arr[i]);
    }

    int k;
    scanf("%i ", &k);
    if(k>0)
        rshift(arr, n, k);

    if(k<0)
        rl(arr, n, k);

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void rl(int array[], int len, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        rlo(array,len);
}

void rlo(int array[], int len)
{
    int temp = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < (len - 1); i++)
        array[i] = array[i+1];
    array[len - 1] = temp;
}

void rshiftonce(int arr1[], int length) {
    int temp = arr1[length - 1]; //временно сохраняем последний элемент
    for(int x = (length - 2); x >= 0; x--) //начиная с предпоследнего элемента двигаемся в обратном направлении по индексам
        arr1[x+1] = arr1[x]; //значение следующего элемента теперь станет зн текущего
    arr1[0] = temp; 
}

void rshift(int arr1[], int length, int times) //тоже самое только вызывается по циклу times раз
{
    for(int i = 0; i<times; i++)
        rshiftonce(arr1, length);
}
```

Comment: Знаете, а перепишите-та вы свой O(kn) алгоритм на O(n). Посмотреть на идею, как сделать любой сдвиг за два прохода, см. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1094178/195342).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас предполагается, направление и количество сдвигов определяется числом `k`, если `> 0` - сдвиг вправо на указанное число, `< 0` - вслево.

```c
void rl(int array[], int len, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        rlo(array,len);
}
```

В функции `rl` вы указали условие `i < n`, т.к. `i = 0`, а `n = k` (в вашем случает отрицательно), то это условие всегда будет `false` и цикл не выполнится. Можете поменять на что-то подобное (ну или перевисать свой вариант):

```c
void rl(int array[], int len, int n)
{
    for (; n<0; n++)
        rlo(array,len);
}
```